# How to make cell array size equal in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array. For example, The dimension of this cell is `[2x3 , 3x3 , 2x4]`. I want to find the maximum size of this array and make this cell array in equal size. I want to add zeros to the minimum cell size to make it as equal to maximum cell size.

I tried with this code:

```
sz = cellfun(@(x)size(x,2), A);
minLength = min(sz);
B = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)x(1:minLength), A, 'uniformoutput', false));'
```

But its not working. It would be nice if anybody help me out.

Comment: What's the dimension of the cell again?   I can understand [3, 3, 4] or [2 3 2] but not [2x3, 3x3, 2x4]

Comment: In my cell array , there are three cell element and each cell element has different size. Thats why I wrote {2x3, 3x3, 2x4}. @OfekShilon

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output for the `{[2x3], [3x3], [2x4]}` case? I'm not really understanding what the goal is.

Comment: I really can't understand what you want. Do you want a row-matrix as an output (filled with zeros)? And if yes, in what dimensions? Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
A = {rand(2,3), rand(3,3), rand(2,4)}
% Find the maximum numbers rows (dims(1)) and the maximum number of columns (dims(2))
dims = max(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)size(x), A, 'uni', 0)'));
%Pad each element of A with zeros so that it's size becomes dims
B = cellfun(@(x)[x,zeros(size(x,1),dims(2)-size(x,2));zeros(dims(1)-size(x,1),dims(2))], A,'uni', 0)
```

This results in

```
B = 

    [3x4 double]    [3x4 double]    [3x4 double]
```

And more specifically:

```
>> B{1}

ans =

    0.9028    0.5791    0.0366         0
    0.5763    0.0658    0.3373         0
         0         0         0         0

>> B{2}

ans =

    0.0764    0.1326    0.4413         0
    0.2463    0.0238    0.3726         0
    0.0299    0.2610    0.1408         0

>> B{3}

ans =

    0.6266    0.6141    0.5653    0.5951
    0.3176    0.0741    0.5795    0.2600
         0         0         0         0
```